# Why does the board only show one x in the console and why can't I switcch from x to o's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Whenever I try to switch from an x to an o using a global variable, I get an error that says "Turn is undefined". So i moved everything into a single function to get rid of the need for global but it still doesn't work. Then after setting up some prints i realized that when you click multiple boxes the board[] gets rewritten in its entirety instead of just assigning a value and keeping that value. How do i fix these? For a clearer picture check the console after clicking 2 different squares.

```
import turtle

from turtle import *

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
setup(601,601)
#Creating Menu option buttons
def button(length):
    for i in range(4):
        pen.forward(length)
        pen.left(90)

def column(n, length):
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(-100,250)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.left(270)
    for i in range(n):
        button(length)
        pen.forward(length)
    pen.penup()
    pen.left(90)
    pen.forward(n * length)
    pen.left(180)
    pen.pendown()

column(5, 100)

#Menu Options
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-100, 190)
pen.write("START GAME", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-75, 90)
pen.write("RULES", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-97, -10)
pen.write("HIGH SCORE", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-65, -110)
pen.write("FAQ", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-93, -210)
pen.write("QUIT GAME", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))


def runGame():
    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    speed(0)
    setup(1366,738)
    title("Group 3's tictactoe")
    pensize(15)


    #Rows
    def dRow():
        up()
        goto(-500,-100)
        down()
        forward(1000)
        up()
        goto(-500, 100)
        down()
        forward(1000)
    dRow()
    #columns
    def dCol():
        up()
        goto(-175,-400)
        left(90)
        down()
        forward(1000)
        up()
        goto(175, -400)
        down()
        forward(1000)
    dCol()

    #Win conditions
    def place(x,y):
        global turn
        #Creating Board
        board = ["","","",
                 "","","",
                 "","","",] 
        turn = "X"
        point = ""

        #create X's
        def Xs(x, y):
            up()
            goto(x+30, y-35)
            setheading(130)
            down()
            forward(100)
            up()
            goto(x+30, y+40)
            setheading(230)
            down()
            forward(100)
            up()
            print(x, y)

        #Create O's
        def Os(x, y):
            up()
            goto(x,y-80)
            setheading(0)
            down()
            circle(80)
            up()
            print(x, y)

        #Check what square was clicked and assign that an (x or O) value to that point
        if -526<x<-182 and 360>y>107:
            point = 0
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -168<x<167 and 360>y>107:
            point = 1
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif 182<x<504 and 360>y>107:
            point = 2
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -506<x<-184 and 92>y>-92:
            point = 3
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -167<x<167 and 92>y>-92:
            point = 4
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = board[int(point)] + str(turn)
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif 185<x<505 and 92>y>-92:
            point = 5
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -504<x<-182 and -108>y>-360:
            point = 6
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -167<x<166 and -108>y>-360:
            point = 7
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = board[int(point)] + str(turn)
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif 185<x<531 and -108>y>-360:
            point = 8
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = board[int(point)] + str(turn)
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        else:
            print("Do something")


        print("The current entire board is: ",board)

        def drawPieces(board):
            for piece in board:
                if piece == "X":
                    Xs(x,y)
                elif board == "O":
                    Os(x,y)

        def clicked(x,y):
            if board[0] == "X" and board[4] == "X" and board[8] == "X":
                style = ('Courier', 80, 'bold')
                write('You WIN!', font=style, align='center')
            else:
                global turn
                if turn == "X":
                    turn = "O"
                    drawPieces(board)
                else:
                    turn = "X"
                    drawPieces(board)
                print("This turn is: ",turn)
        clicked(x, y)



    onscreenclick(place)
    mainloop()

#Making options clickable
def btnclick(x,y):
    if -100 < x < 1 and 250 > y > 150:
        print("Start Game")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
        runGame()

    elif -100 < x < 1 and 150 > y > 50:
        print("Rules")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
        screen = turtle.Screen()
        answer = screen.textinput("Welcome to Our GAME!", "Whats your name?")

    elif -100 < x < 1 and 50 > y > -50:
        print("Highscore")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif -100 < x < 1 and -50 > y > -150:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif -100 < x < 1 and -150 > y > -250:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif -100 < x < 1 and -250 > y > -350:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    else:
        print("Click One Of The Options!")
        print(x, y)



turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick, 1)
turtle.listen()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: One of the most common pieces of advice given to new coders by experienced coders is to **avoid global variables**.  There are lots of longwinded explanations as to why you should avoid them, but they all boil down to "because they make bugs happen".  If you can write your code to not use a global, you won't have this bug.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major issue in your code is, that `borad` and `turn` are initialized every time when `place` is invoked.

> ```py
> def place(x,y):
>         global turn
>         #Creating Board
>         board = ["","","",
>                  "","","",
>                  "","","",] 
>         turn = "X"
>         point = ""
> ```

Thus a new board is created and the turn is set `"X"` every time when a new turn starts.

Create a `bord` and `turn` in global namespace and use it in `place`:

```py
#Creating Board
board = ["","","",
              "","","",
              "","","",] 
turn = "X"

def runGame():
    # [...]

    #Win conditions
    def place(x,y):
        global turn, board

        point = ""

        #create X's
        # [...]
```

Furthermore there are some issues in `clicked`. Use the global variables `board` and `turn` in clicked, too. `drawPieces` does not work at all, because `x` and `y` never change and all the pieces are drawn at the same position. It is sufficient to draw the new piece. Draw on piece by `Xs` respectively `Os` in `clicked`:

```py
def runGame():
    # [...]

    #Win conditions
    def place(x,y):
        global turn, board

        point = ""
        # [...]

        def clicked(x,y):
            global board, turn
            if board[0] == "X" and board[4] == "X" and board[8] == "X":
                style = ('Courier', 80, 'bold')
                write('You WIN!', font=style, align='center')
            else:
                if turn == "X":
                    Xs(x,y)
                    turn = "O"
                else:
                    Os(x,y)
                    turn = "X"
                print("This turn is: ",turn)
        clicked(x, y)
```

Complete code:

```py
import turtle

from turtle import *

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
setup(601,601)
#Creating Menu option buttons
def button(length):
    for i in range(4):
        pen.forward(length)
        pen.left(90)

def column(n, length):
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(-100,250)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.left(270)
    for i in range(n):
        button(length)
        pen.forward(length)
    pen.penup()
    pen.left(90)
    pen.forward(n * length)
    pen.left(180)
    pen.pendown()

column(5, 100)

#Menu Options
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-100, 190)
pen.write("START GAME", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-75, 90)
pen.write("RULES", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-97, -10)
pen.write("HIGH SCORE", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-65, -110)
pen.write("FAQ", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-93, -210)
pen.write("QUIT GAME", font=("Arial",12,"normal"))

#Creating Board
board = ["","","",
              "","","",
              "","","",] 
turn = "X"

def runGame():
    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    speed(0)
    setup(1366,738)
    title("Group 3's tictactoe")
    pensize(15)

    #Rows
    def dRow():
        up()
        goto(-500,-100)
        down()
        forward(1000)
        up()
        goto(-500, 100)
        down()
        forward(1000)
    dRow()
    #columns
    def dCol():
        up()
        goto(-175,-400)
        left(90)
        down()
        forward(1000)
        up()
        goto(175, -400)
        down()
        forward(1000)
    dCol()

    #Win conditions
    def place(x,y):
        global turn, board

        point = ""

        #create X's
        def Xs(x, y):
            up()
            goto(x+30, y-35)
            setheading(130)
            down()
            forward(100)
            up()
            goto(x+30, y+40)
            setheading(230)
            down()
            forward(100)
            up()
            print(x, y)

        #Create O's
        def Os(x, y):
            up()
            goto(x,y-80)
            setheading(0)
            down()
            circle(80)
            up()
            print(x, y)

        #Check what square was clicked and assign that an (x or O) value to that point
        if -526<x<-182 and 360>y>107:
            point = 0
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -168<x<167 and 360>y>107:
            point = 1
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif 182<x<504 and 360>y>107:
            point = 2
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -506<x<-184 and 92>y>-92:
            point = 3
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -167<x<167 and 92>y>-92:
            point = 4
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = board[int(point)] + str(turn)
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif 185<x<505 and 92>y>-92:
            point = 5
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -504<x<-182 and -108>y>-360:
            point = 6
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = turn
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif -167<x<166 and -108>y>-360:
            point = 7
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = board[int(point)] + str(turn)
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        elif 185<x<531 and -108>y>-360:
            point = 8
            print("This is square: ",point)
            board[int(point)] = board[int(point)] + str(turn)
            print("this board space is: ", board[point], board)
        else:
            print("Do something")


        print("The current entire board is: ",board)

        def drawPieces(board):
            for piece in board:
                if piece == "X":
                    Xs(x,y)
                elif piece == "O":
                    Os(x,y)

        def clicked(x,y):
            global board, turn
            if board[0] == "X" and board[4] == "X" and board[8] == "X":
                style = ('Courier', 80, 'bold')
                write('You WIN!', font=style, align='center')
            else:
                if turn == "X":
                    Xs(x,y)
                    turn = "O"
                else:
                    Os(x,y)
                    turn = "X"
                print("This turn is: ",turn)
        clicked(x, y)



    onscreenclick(place)
    mainloop()

#Making options clickable
def btnclick(x,y):
    if -100 < x < 1 and 250 > y > 150:
        print("Start Game")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
        runGame()

    elif -100 < x < 1 and 150 > y > 50:
        print("Rules")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
        screen = turtle.Screen()
        answer = screen.textinput("Welcome to Our GAME!", "Whats your name?")

    elif -100 < x < 1 and 50 > y > -50:
        print("Highscore")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif -100 < x < 1 and -50 > y > -150:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif -100 < x < 1 and -150 > y > -250:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    elif -100 < x < 1 and -250 > y > -350:
        print("Hi")
        print(x, y)
        turtle.clearscreen()
    else:
        print("Click One Of The Options!")
        print(x, y)



turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick, 1)
turtle.listen()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: When i do this I get an error that says board is not defined, despite already declaring it as global. ```board[int(point)] = board[int(point)] + str(turn)```

Comment: @TyrellReid So you did it wrong. Of course I've tested the code and it works fine for me. I've added the complete code to the answer.

Comment: I see what it was. It works now. I had moved board and turn out of place() but they were still inside rungame(). so for global variables to work properly they have to be declared before any other function?